# ITMS-90809 Error while uploading my app to app store connect

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, inappbrowser, itms-90809

I've seen this error happening a lot and ive been searching for hours but nothing seems to solve this issue. when i send my app for review i get that error. its obviously cause i was using uiwebview and not the standard new one wkwebview. but i went ahead and downloaded the plugin:

```
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

But when i compile it with this plugin my build fails. i made sure that i am using ios@5.1.1 or ios@6.0.0 but it still does not work.

I thought inappbrowser might be an issue but i updated it to 3.2.0 since it has a patch specifically for this situation. my build still crashes. the only other plugins i am using are:

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist

cordova-plugin-splashscreen

cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

Does anyone know if any of these plugins might potentially be causing an issue? does anyone know a solution to this issue. my app is all finished, and it would be a shame not to post it now!

Comment: I have built and passed apple ios 13 with wkwebview with 5.1.1 and the kleeb inapp patch.  I have these 2 cordova-plugin-whitelist, cordova-plugin-splashscreen and NOT cordova-plugin-screen-orientation.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the flag `WKWebViewOnly` if you publish with 5.1.1

See https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html